# Como limitar os caracteres de um label?

Tags: java, html, jsp

Estou num projeto e-commerce, e preciso exibir o nome de um produto. Estou pensando em utilizar um label para isso. A ideia é deixar x caracteres visíveis, se o titulo ultrapassar esse numero x de caracteres, exibir "...". Eu não sei como fazer isso, nem se a melhor opção ou se é possível com um label.

Observações: Estou utilizando **jsp** para recuperar o titulo do produto do banco de dados. A linguagem de programação é **JAVA** e utilizo html e **jsp**. eu consigo recuperar o nome com `<%anuncio.getTitulo()%>`.

Alguma dica ou sugestão de como fazer isso?

Comment: Se eu entendi bem, quando o titulo do anúncio que você está pegando através do `<%anuncio.getTitulo%>` ultrapassar o número **X** de letras será exibido `...` no título, isso?

Comment: Se for isso mesmo que você quer fazer, jogue o retorno do seu get `<%anuncio.getTitulo%>` dentro de uma variável string e utilize o método `length()` que te retorna o numero de letras de uma variável **String**, faça uma condição, se esse número retornado ultrapassar o número de letras que você quer basta mandar exibir `...` senão exibe `<%anuncio.getTitulo%>` mesmo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Java Servlet 3.0 ou superior

Caso você esteja utilizando a Java Servlet versão 3.0 ou superior você pode usar esse trecho de código:

```
<lable><c:out value="${anuncio.getTitulo().length() <= maxSize ? anuncio.getTitulo() : anuncio.getTitulo().substring(0, maxSize).concat('...')}" /></lable>
```

**maxSize** é o tamanho máximo que você quer no label.

Se você vai utilizar isso em vários locais, criar um *tagfile* é uma boa opção.

#### Java Servlet inferior a versão 3.0

Outra opção, caso você esteja utilizando uma versão inferior a Java Servlet 3.0 é utilizar o seguinte *scriptlet*:

```
<label>
    <%
        int maxSize = 5;
        String titulo = anuncio.getTitulo();
        out.println(titulo.length() <= maxSize ? titulo : titulo.substring(0, maxSize).concat("..."));
    %>
</label>
```

Comment: Funcionou com a segunda opção. Obrigada!

Answer (score 2):

Você pode tambem fazer essa tratativa utilizando somente HTML e CSS:

```css
label{
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    word-wrap: hyphenate;
    max-width: 100px;
    display: block;
}
label > span{
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <span>
    Isso é um texte com um label muito grande
  </span>
</label>
```

Abraço

Answer (score 0):

Não sei como fazer isto em jsp, mas em javascript direto no html seria o seguinte:

em js:

```
<label id="label">Estou num projeto e-commerce, e preciso exibir o nome de um produto</label>


(function(){
var element = document.getElementById("label");
element.innerHTML  = 
                        //@inicio, //@comprimento
 element.innerHTML.substr(0, 10)+"...";
})()
```

O código substitui o texto do elemento pelo seu próprio texto "quebrado" em uma quantidade x de caracteres (incluindo espaços) e concatena com "..."

https://jsfiddle.net/a5r375eb/